# Click button to copy text to another div with angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a list of Items with different button with them. **[Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/nPvZBrNC6YAntpEGFgi0?p=preview)**

Quick View:

[image]

I want something like if I click on any of the buttons, related text will be copy to the div above. Also  if I click on the button again it will removed from the Div.Same for each of the buttons. [I added manually one to show how it may display ]

I am not sure how to do that in Angular. Any help will be my life saver.

```
<div ng-repeat="item in csTagGrp">
    <ul>
      <li ng-repeat="value in item.csTags">
        <div class="pull-left">
          <button type="button" ng-class='{active: value.active && !value.old}' class="btn btn-default btn-xs">{{value.keys}}</button>
          <span>=</span>
        </div>
        <div class="pull-left cs-tag-item-list">
          <span>{{value.tags}}</span>
        </div>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest thing would be to use `$scope.tags` object to store selected tags and add/remove them with the scope method similar to this:

```
$scope.tags = {};

$scope.toggleTag = function(tag) {
    if (!$scope.tags[tag]) {
        $scope.tags[tag] = true;
    }
    else {
        delete $scope.tags[tag];
    }
};
```

**Demo:** http://plnkr.co/edit/FrifyCrl0yP0T8l8XO4K?p=info

Comment: Why you are so awesome ? :) This is perfect. In addition is this possible to have key actions with it ? Numbers in the button represent the keyboard keys. For example : If I press "1" in keyboard it will do same like clicking.

Comment: Also special thanks for the addition notes you  gave. It helps me much to understand how it works

Comment: @Raihan This is a little trickier. Check updated demo, I made basic implementation (remember to focus buttons area before using keyboard).

Comment: Do I have  to focus that div in order to perform ? No way to focus only the page to do same ?

Comment: Anyway  "<Special Thanks />"

Comment: Well you can also bind key event to document itself if you really want. Check updated demo again.

Comment: One thing I noticed if I change the value of Button like 1 changed to  A, keyboard don't work. I mean what if I have other keyboard value from A-z and 0-9 .  Do I need to write anything more then the directive you added ?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `ng-click` to put in your scope the selected value, and then display this value instead of "Win".

http://plnkr.co/edit/IzwZFtRBfSiEcHGicc9l?p=preview

```
<div class="myboard">
  <span>{{selected.tags}}</span>
</div>
...
<button type="button" ng-click="select(value)">{{value.keys}}</button>
```

Comment: This is very nice but there can be multiple texts also. Like if I click Win and then I click  respondent , Both will stay there. [Win , respondent ...]
Also  if I click the related button again, text will hide.Thanks

Comment: Oh I skiped that part. Here is a fixed plunkr where `ng-click` sets/unsets a `selected` property: http://plnkr.co/edit/x1rE6ss0GHTLT8vj4sUZ?p=preview